# Two Years Schengen multivisa with 15 days of maximum stay

Tags: schengen-visas

I've just got a multi entry Schengen visa to Greece. All my previous multi visas were with 90 days maximum duration and I was able to use them for many times. So what does my current visa mean? I can spend only 15 days in Schengen Zone within 2 years? I don't understand what is the purpose for giving 2 years multi visa for only 15 days, which will be over for just one trip.

If anybody was in this kind of situation please help.

Comment: Please add a picture of the (redacted) visa.

Comment: Did you by chance apply for 15 days on the first visit ?  If yes, this may have a 'blackout' moment during the issueing.

Comment: I would assume this is 15 day maximum PER entry.

Comment: Yes I have applied for 15 days for first entry.... And the embassy just confirmed that these 15 days are total number of days for all the entries. Absolutely non-sense....